# Problem with Cyrillic encoding and Facebook graph

Tags: php, facebook, encoding, graph

I am trying to make a simple Facebook app that takes some data from the user wall. The problem is that most of my friends write in Cyrillic and when I try to make a graph api call like https://graph.facebook.com/userID/home?access_token=someToken I get the data and all the Cyrillic characters are replaced with something like that "\u0442\u0438 \u043f\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0440\u044f\u0442".

So I am wondering if there is a PHP function that translates this encoding into something readable. I hope that you can help me. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some more searching on this site I found out this solution

[Cyrillic characters in PHP's json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410704/cyrillic-characters-in-phps-json-encode)

I am using the Zend framework function for encoding that is pointed out in the answers. I am responding to my question so that if anyone ever stuck on something like that and come to my question searching for the answer he will find out the solution.