# php json_encode with cyrillic characters

Tags: php, json

Not to reinvent the wheel I refer to already existing [Cyrillic characters in PHP's json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410704/cyrillic-characters-in-phps-json-encode).

The question is: what are those characters, what do they mean: \u0435, \u0434 and so on? I guess there is nothing to do with number of bytes, is that just a serial number in UTF-8 that corresponds to cyrillic symbols "е", "д" and so on respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are Unicode escape sequences that reference characters in the Unicode character set by denoting their code points in hexadecimal.

From the [JSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5):

> Any character may be escaped.  If the character is in the Basic
> Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be
> represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed
> by the lowercase letter `u`, followed by four hexadecimal digits that
> encode the character's code point.  The hexadecimal letters `A` though
> `F` can be upper or lowercase.  So, for example, a string containing
> only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as
> "`\u005C`".

Although these characters do not need to be escaped (see [*unescaped* rule](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5)), [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) does encode any character except those character that are also in US-ASCII (see [source of *json.c*](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/json/json.c?revision=311708&view=markup#l482)) to avoid encoding issues with US-ASCII-based protocols.

So inside a JSON string, `\u0435` references the character at U+0435 that is the CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE (`е`) and  `\u0434` references the character at U+0434 that is the CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER DE (`д`).