# get cyrillic words from json string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

Get Cyrillic words from JSON string in PHP?  JSON string is unstructured and any type.

Example:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Вилен", "lastName":"Авангард"},
    {"firstName":"Станислав", "lastName":"Андрей"}
]}
```

Output:

```
Вилен Авангард Станислав Андрей
```

Comment: Ok, now what is your problem? What do you try to solve it? Your question is not clear, please edit

Comment: Is the output is your expected output?

Comment: sorry. my english is very bad. i tried many regex but not work. i just need all cyrilic words any strings.

Comment: the JSON is structured.

Comment: does `cyrillic` mean anything other than English?

Comment: if I am correct check **[this](https://regex101.com/r/pL3pV1/1)**

Comment: @rock321987 yes correct. can you write preg_match version in PHP.  preg_match('(?![A-Za-z]+)\p{L}+/g', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE); it doesnt work. error: "Unknown modifier '\'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cyrillic characters in PHP's json\_encode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410704/cyrillic-characters-in-phps-json-encode)

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade its different. i only need cyrillic characters. no need special characters and latin/A-Z/ characters.

Comment: use `(?![A-Za-z]+)\p{Cyrillic}+` for `Cyrillic`.

Comment: Thank you All. "/(*UTF8)(?![A-Za-z]+)\p{Cyrillic}+/" this is works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do with regular expression the check the [online script here](https://regex101.com/r/eK8fB9/1)

**For general purpose:**

You need to check the `firstName` or `lastName` is english or not, if not then store them in an array and at the end just implode them as the result demand.

```
$json = '{"employees":[
            {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
            {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
            {"firstName":"Вилен", "lastName":"Авангард"},
            {"firstName":"Станислав", "lastName":"Андрей"}
        ]}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$out = array();
foreach($arr['employees'] as $value){
    if(strlen($value['firstName']) != mb_strlen($value['firstName'], 'utf-8'))
        $out[] = $value['firstName'];
    if(strlen($value['lastName']) != mb_strlen($value['lastName'], 'utf-8'))
        $out[] = $value['lastName'];
}

echo implode(" ", $out); //Вилен Авангард Станислав Андрей
```

> **Note:** You need mbstring php module installed.

Comment: thank you. but json string is any structured. above json is just example. some response is not include firstName, lastName..,, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. "/(*UTF8)(?![A-Za-z]+)\p{Cyrillic}+/" this is works perfect.